# file.exists() returning false in Android unit test

Tags: android-unit-testing

I am trying to test some file related logic in an Android unit test, but whenever I call `file.exists()` it always returns `false` for some reason. Here is a boiled down example of a test case I have:

```
 @Test
    fun `some test case`() {
        val file = File("/storage/emulated/0/Photo1234.jpg")
        assertTrue(file.exists()) // Fails
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I've also tried `file.absoluteFile.exists()` but that returns `false` also.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was not calling `file.createNewFile()`.